# maatwebsite/excel Export In Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, export-to-csv, maatwebsite-excel

How to set header value bold  in maatwebsite/excel Export In Laravel ?And also how to bold specific raw and set background.

Comment: which version you are using of maatwebsite/Excel ?

Comment: "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0",  ---i want  header text bold  for .csv not for xslx. so it is possible?

Comment: Maatwebsite provide a style on row that you will find on google easily and I have no idea about it will work on CSV format or not.

Comment: ok may be it not working.

Comment: If CSV is open in excel then it looks like sheet so it may work.

Answer (score 0):

Snippet below sets a background color and boldness for the header row.

```
class ExcelExport implements WithStyles
{
     [...]

     public function styles($sheet)
     {
         return [
             1 => [
                 'font' => ['bold' => true],

                 'fill' => [
                     'fillType'   => Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                     'startColor' => ['rgb' => "ffff00"],
                 ],
             ],
         ];
     }


}
```